# Need help cloning a GitHub repository because of public key issues

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh

I am trying to clone a private GitHub repository in a server that I am trying to get up and running on a virtual machine.

No matter what I do, I keep getting the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried a bunch of things. For starters, I made sure that I made my rsa keys correctly by following [GitHub's tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/). I am also sure that my public rsa key found at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` was correctly copied over to my GitHub account's ssh keys.

My config file at `~/.ssh/config` looks like the following:

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I have tried cloning a public repository and a private repository, and both don't work.

When I go to clone the repository I am executing the following command:

```
sudo git clone git@github.mit.edu:<GitHub Name>/<Repo Name>.git
```

If I execute the command without `sudo`, I get the following error:

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir '<Repo Name>'.: Permission denied
```

I am inside of a Python virtual environment when I do all of this. Does that make any difference?

I have been reading Stack Overflow posts related to this matter, but none of them are helping me address my issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Do not use `sudo`

Comment: So when I don't use `sudo` I get the error `fatal: could not create work tree dir '<Repo Name>'.: Permission denied`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `sudo` so Git is using ssh keys of user `root`.

To make this work you'd have to call git without `sudo`.

> So when I don't use sudo I get the error fatal: could not create work
>   tree dir 'cardlearning'.: Permission denied

Make sure current user has write permission in directory you are executing the clone.

You can't clone into existing directory so as a workaround you can:

```
$ sudo mkdir tmp
$ sudo chown $USER: tmp
$ git clone git@github.mit.edu:<GitHub Name>/<Repo Name>.git tmp/cardlearning
$ mv tmp/cardlearning ./cardlearning
$ rmdir tmp
```

Comment: When I do this, I seem to get a bit further, but I get some errors around my `config` file in `~/.ssh/config`, namely: `/home/agaidis/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: addkeystoagent /home/agaidis/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: usekeychain /home/agaidis/.ssh/config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Comment: Remove invalid options from your `~/.ssh/config` file. It should be fine to remove all four directives pasted in your question.

Comment: Thank you! That really saved me there.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your user has permissions to write to the directory you are in.

or execute

```
git clone git@github.mit.edu:<GitHub Name>/<Repo Name>.git ~/myRepo
```

to place it in the `myRepo` subdirectory of your home directory.

Do not use sudo to edit your ssh config when using a `~` referenced path, as you may end up editing the `root` user's `ssh` preferences and not your users. Likewise do not clone repositories using `sudo` as it will attempt to connect using the `root` user's `ssh` key.